# REST Resource vs Services

Tags: php, rest, oop

I have [created some code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96021/restful-api-building-dependency-injection-factory-patterns) to make calls to an external API (that I did not create). However, it has been described as 'Service-centric', while REST APIs are 'Resource-centric'.

What exactly needs changed to turn this into a service based call? I don't understand what the difference is. I understand I need to use HTTP verbs but I *thought* I was doing that already with cURL. Is this possible with cURL?

The API I have been passed contains a bunch of resource URLs as an example;

> GET http://api.privateservice.com/Person?ID=123
>
> POST http://api.privateservice.com/Person/SaveDetails/123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of resources as nouns, ie objects or records in your database. Think of actions as verbs, ie function calls.

The first example is indeed resource-centric. It's GETting a resource of type Person identified by 123.

The second example is not resource-centric because it's essentially a function call. REST and HTTP already establish conventions for saving a resource. In this case you simply need to PUT to the resource's URL, ie the same URL you retrieved with GET.

So upload the JSON (or whatever format) using:

```
PUT http://api.privateservice.com/Person?ID=123
```

If you are only passing in a few attributes, not the whole resource, there's another standard for that, PATCH:

```
PATCH http://api.privateservice.com/Person?ID=123
```

BTW It's a bit cleaner to use `http://api.privateservice.com/people/123` as the URL.

Comment: I don't have control over the API itself, just the ability to connect to it.